# SQL Server Isolation level real world example

Tags: sql-server, locking, isolation-level, read-uncommitted

Let's say we need to develop a bidding application such as one in eBay. We don't want one user's bidding to block another user's bidding, which will result in slow response. Also, when I place a bid based on the highest price I see, I don't want to arrive at the end with the app saying that sorry, the highest price was no longer the same; while I am placing the bid someone has pushed the price higher.

Which isolation level should we use? I was thinking of `Read Uncommitted`
for dirty read and no locking but not sure.

I would like to hear more real-world examples/use-cases for isolation level in SQL Server (or in general, any other database software, if there are similarities between them regarding isolation levels). For me I find it not very efficient just looking at definitions.

Thank you.

Comment: Your explanation kind of contradicts itself. First you say you don't want somebody to be able to outbid another while one person is bidding but then you say you do. I have been in a situation on ebay where I was placing a bid only to find out I am no longer the highest bidder. Consider what would happen in your scenario if you allowed two simultaneous bids and they are both the same price. Which one wins?

Answer (score 1):

`READ UNCOMMITTED` sounds about right, in context of the scenario you envision... but that scenario sounds pretty bad!

> when I place a bid based on the highest price I see, I don't want to arrive at the end with the app saying that sorry, the highest price was no longer the same; while I am placing the bid someone has pushed the price higher.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but do you mean if someone else bid while you were *preparing* your bid? If so, how else is it meant to work? Will you win, even though you bid lower, simply because the *time* of *starting* your bid was earlier? That won't work. This has to be decided at the time your bid is *submitted*.

Really, this should run with `READ COMMITTED`, so that the user's bid is affected by all the previous ones - at the point that is it submitted. That is a requirement for a sensible auction. Bids should run in temporal sequence, wrapped by `TRANSACTION`s, and always be subject to the latest maximum at the time that their transaction began, i.e. when the user hit the Submit button, they should be subject to the sum of all bids submitted before theirs.

Comment: This question appeared once I sat for a test so I wrote as far as I remembered, with two points I remember the best when they describe the scenario : currently the response time is slow and blocking occurs + the issue with higer bid when I arrive at the end. A related thought : How would time-out, such as one in eBay, fit into this picture of bidding? For example, the bid stills depends on who starts first, but time-out avoid having him hogging others. Does it sound like a reasonable scenario ?

Comment: I'm not an expert. But I think we need to make a distinction between a user starting to enter a bid, versus the _system_ running a database transaction after the user has submitted their bid. The former might take a while (if the user is indecisive), shouldn't cause any locking, and shouldn't stop other users from submitting higher bids if they are quicker. The latter should be relatively much faster, should be wrapped in a transaction to disallow dirty reads (e.g. inconsistent views of the current max bid) and ensure sequence; this would also ensure bids are processed in order, which is good.